# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los valores de las filas en una tabla dinámica usando un evento en un botón?

Tags: javascript, php

Me encuentro con el dilema de no saber como traer los datos que se encuentran en cada una de las filas de mi tabla por medio de la escucha de un botón que se encuentra allí mismo. Este es mi código.

Además, quiero que se muestre por medio de un modals toda la información del portátil especifico

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Dependencia</th>
                                <th>Colaborador</th>
                  <th>Objeto</th>
                  <th>Sede</th>
                  <th>Fecha</th>
                  <th>Informacion</th>
    
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
    
                    include "php/conexion.php";
    
                    $mysqli = getConn();
    
                    $consulta="SELECT inventario.inventario_id AS ID,dependencia.dependencia_nombre AS Dependencia,colaborador.colaborador_nombre AS Colaborador,objeto.objeto_nombre AS Equipo,sede_corhuila.sede_corhuila_nombre AS Sede, inventario.fecha AS Fecha FROM registro_objeto INNER JOIN inventario ON registro_objeto.registro_objeto_inventario=inventario.inventario_id INNER JOIN dependencia ON inventario.inventario_dependencia=dependencia.dependencia_id INNER JOIN colaborador ON colaborador.colaborador_dependencia=dependencia.dependencia_id INNER JOIN objeto ON inventario.inventario_objeto_id=objeto.objeto_id INNER JOIN sede_corhuila ON inventario.inventario_sede_id=sede_corhuila.sede_corhuila_id;";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($consulta);
    
                    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                      echo "<tr>
                      <td id='".$row["ID"]."'>".$row['ID']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Dependencia']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Colaborador']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Equipo']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Sede']."</td>
                      <td>".$row['Fecha']."</td>
                      <td><button value='datos'>Informacion</button></td>
                      </tr>";
    
                    }
                ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y carece de detalles necesarios para ofrecerte una respuesta 100% acertada. Sin embargo, haré mi mejor esfuerzo.

La opción fácil es declarar una función en `JavaScript` que:

- Reciba como parámetro el id del registro
- Abra el modal
- Haga una petición vía `Ajax` para consultar la información específica del registro *o del portátil que mencionas*
- Muestre en el modal la información obtenida de `ajax`

```js
//La función recibe como parámetro el id del regitro
function mostrarInfo(idRegistro){
  //Para el ejemplo, se muestra el id en un alert, 
  //pero este id sería usado por ajax para consultar los datos del registro específico
  alert(idRegistro);
  //Código para abrir el modal...
  //Código para hacer la petición ajax con el id recibido
  //Con la respuesta de ajax, se mostraría la información del registro en los campos correspondientes
};
```

```html
<td>
  <!-- Usando un id de ejemplo... -->
  <button value='datos' onclick='mostrarInfo(25)'>Informacion</button>
</td>
```

La función se ejecutaría al hacer click en el botón, el cual tendría el id del registro o el id de lo que llamas **portátil**:

```
<button value='datos' onclick='mostrarInfo(".$row['ID'].")'>Informacion</button>
```

Si desconoces `ajax`, en esta misma comunidad encuentras información detallada sobre cómo usarlo.